# Problem with JavaFX pane.getChildren().remove() at lambda

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I have written a code:

```
public class MousePosition extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Text text = new Text();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise 8");
        primaryStage.show();

        scene.setOnMouseReleased(e -> pane.getChildren().clear());

        scene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            showCoordinates(pane, text, e);
        });

        scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            showCoordinates(pane, text, e);
        });


    }

    private void showCoordinates(Pane pane, Text text, MouseEvent e) {
        text.setText("(" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
        text.setX(e.getX());
        text.setY(e.getY());
        if (!pane.getChildren().contains(text))
            pane.getChildren().add(text);
    }
}
```

It should:

> display the mouse position when the mouse button is clicked (see
>   Figure 15.28a), and the other displays the mouse position when the
>   mouse button is pressed and ceases to display it when the mouse button
>   is released.

But my lambda doesn't work:

```
scene.setOnMouseReleased(e -> pane.getChildren().clear());
```

It simply does nothing. 
When I changed it to  `scene.setOnMouseReleased(e -> text.setText(""));` It also does nothing. But when I use  `scene.setOnMouseReleased(e -> System.out.println("0"));`, it works.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Please include an entire program. This is minimal, but it needs the includes and the main() so that we can see how it is called and to compile it ourselves with a debugger. You've made it difficult to help us.

Comment: carefully read the text surrounding _Figure 15.28a_ ..

Answer (score 1):

please try to explicitly update the UI component(s) in your eventhandler on the javafx application thread:

`scene.setOnMouseReleased(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> pane.getChildren().clear()));`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-